# Change label with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, networking, alamofire

I want to put the information I get from the API into the corresponding Label inside, I use the Alamofire to get the API information and put the corresponding Label inside, but I found that my Label text has not been changed, would like to ask this happen What's the problem? Who can answer me for me? Thank you

Here is my `Information` class:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
class Information {
    var account:String?
    var date:String?
    var name:String?
    var sex:String?
    var born:String?
    var phoneNumber:String?
    var email:String?

    init(account:String,date:String,name:String,sex:String,born:String,phoneNumber:String,email:String) {
        self.account = account
        self.date = date
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex
        self.born = born
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.email = email
    }

    typealias DownlaodComplete = () -> ()



    func downlaodInformation(completion:@escaping DownlaodComplete) {
        Alamofire.request("http://163.18.22.78:81/api/Information/A1001a").responseJSON { response in
             print(response)
            if let json = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                guard let account = json["Account"] as? String ,let date = json["Date"] as? String , let name = json["Name"] as? String , let sex = json["Sex"] as? String , let born = json["Born"] as? String , let phoneNumber = json["PhoneNumber"] as? String , let email = json["Email"] as? String   else {
                    return
                }
                self.account = account
                self.date = date
                self.name = name
                self.sex = sex
                self.born = born
                self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
                self.email = email
                completion()
            }

        }
    }

}
```

And here is my `ViewController`:

```
   var information:Information?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let currentInformation = information {
            currentInformation.downlaodInformation {
                self.accountLabel.text = currentInformation.account
                self.dateLabel.text = currentInformation.date
                self.nameLabel.text = currentInformation.name
                self.sexLabel.text = currentInformation.sex
                self.bornLabel.text = currentInformation.born
                self.phoneNumberLabel.text = currentInformation.phoneNumber
                self.emailLabel.text = currentInformation.email

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you declare `information` to be an `Information` optional

```
var information:Information?
```

But you don't give it an initial value, meaning that it is `nil`

In your `viewDidLoad` you do the right thing and check whether information has a value:

```
if let currentInformation = information
```

But I'm guessing it hasn't, because you haven't created an instance of it. Therefore you don't end up inside your `if let` loop and never calls `downlaodInformation`

So you need to create a new instance of `Information` before you can use it.

#### However

This leads to a problem with your `Information` class.

If I was to instantiate an `Information` object, I'd need to have:

- account
- date
- name
- sex
- born
- phoneNumber
- email

Or..since you've created them as optionals, pass `nil`.

But that is not what you want, is it?

I'm guessing you'd like to do something along the lines of this in your ViewController:

```
let information = Information()
```

and then in `viewDidLoad`

```
information.downloadInformation( currrentInformation in 
    self.accountLabel.text = currentInformation.account
    ....
}
```

To do so you could change your `Information` to not take parameters to its constructor and then create another `struct` which would hold your data.

Something like:

```
struct Information {
    var account:String?
    var date:String?
    var name:String?
    var sex:String?
    var born:String?
    var phoneNumber:String?
    var email:String?
}

class InformationLoader {
    func downloadInformation(completion: (Information?) -> ()) {
        Alamofire.request("http://163.18.22.78:81/api/Information/A1001a").responseJSON{ response in
        print(response)
        if let json = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
            guard let account = json["Account"] as? String,
            let date = json["Date"] as? String, 
            let name = json["Name"] as? String, 
            let sex = json["Sex"] as? String, 
            let born = json["Born"] as? String, 
            let phoneNumber = json["PhoneNumber"] as? String, 
            let email = json["Email"] as? String else {
               completion(nil)
               return
            }
            let information = Information(account: account, date: date, name: name, sex: sex, born: born, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, email: email)
            completion(information)
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd need to change your code in the `ViewController` to:

```
let informationLoader:InformationLoader()
```

In `viewDidLoad`

```
informationLoader.downloadInformation{ currentInformation in
    if let currentInformation = currentInformation {
        //populate your textfields
        self.accountLabel.text = currentInformation.account
        ....
    }
}
```

Hope that makes sense and helps you.

Comment: I tried your method and got the json data (in the debug area), but the view's label was not changed

Comment: OK. So it seems you get a response from your service then. Now the problem is to unwrap it and create a new `Information` object from it. You expect that all fields are filled, and if they are not, then you return nil. As @rashwan-l writes in the comments to his answer it seems that the `phoneNumber` you received from your server was `nil` and therefore the unwrapping fails and you get `nil` in return from the completion block and your labels are not filled out as expected.

Comment: It turned out that I call Phone  of Phone Number, no wonder can not update the label, and now the smooth operation of the very very thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your completion block which will be called whenever `Alamofire` has finished the data request. You can also improve your code a bit by for example have a `onCompletion` block that passes an `Information` object and an `onError` block to display if you have any errors. Example below:

```
func downlaodInformation(parameterOne: String, parameterTwo: Int, onCompletion: @escaping (Information) -> Void, onError: @escaping(NSError)  -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request("http://163.18.22.78:81/api/Information/A1001a").responseJSON { response in
        if let json = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
            let account = json["Account"] as? String
            let date = json["Date"] as? String
            let name = json["Name"] as? String
            let sex = json["Sex"] as? String
            let born = json["Born"] as? String
            let phoneNumber = json["PhoneNumber"] as? String
            let email = json["Email"] as? String

            let information = Information(account: account, date: date, name: name, sex: sex, born: born, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, email: email)
            onCompletion(information)
        } else {
            onError(NSError(domain: "Error while getting data", code: 0, userInfo: nil))
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
downlaodInformation(parameterOne: "someParam", parameterTwo: 123, onCompletion: { (currentInformation) in
    print(currentInformation.account)
    self.accountLabel.text = currentInformation.account
    self.dateLabel.text = currentInformation.date
    self.nameLabel.text = currentInformation.name
    self.sexLabel.text = currentInformation.sex
    self.bornLabel.text = currentInformation.born
    self.phoneNumberLabel.text = currentInformation.phoneNumber
    self.emailLabel.text = currentInformation.email
}) { (error) in
    print(error.domain)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what do I fill in let information = Information()

Comment: I need to give him any parameters, or you can not enter

Comment: @廖豪豪, sure you can. See the updated example. You can add as many parameters you need.

Comment: I fill in like this ` let information = Information(account: account, date: date, name: name, sex: sex, born: born, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, email: email)`

Comment: See the updated example, have you done exact like that? Set a breakpoint in the `onCompletion` block and the `onError` block and see what happens.

Comment: I tried the method you provided, but he did not print anything in the bebug area

Comment: Well your `phoneNumber` was nil and that´s why the `if let` broke. Since you handle optionals in your `Information` we can do as I provided in the new example, check it out. Just tried it and it works.

Comment: My question has been resolved, but still very grateful to you for your help

Comment: Np glad to help, but do notice that the answer you accepted does not contain any error handling which is important when you make web requests. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, I will be done in the wrong piece of this deal, but also thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of mistakes, so here is a working variant. Better to call an updateUI or something like that from the closure. I hope this will help:

ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    @IBOutlet weak var accountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    var information: Information?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        information = Information.init(account: "aaaa", date: "dddd", name: "nnnn", sex: "ssss", born: "bbbb", phoneNumber: "pppp", email: "eeee")
        information?.downlaodInformation(completion:
        {
                self.updateUI()
        })
    }

    func updateUI()
    {
        print("called")
        self.accountLabel.text = information?.account
        self.dateLabel.text = information?.date
        self.nameLabel.text = information?.name
        /*self.sexLabel.text = currentInformation.sex
         self.bornLabel.text = currentInformation.born
         self.phoneNumberLabel.text = currentInformation.phoneNumber
         self.emailLabel.text = currentInformation.email*/
    }
}
```

Information.swift:

```
class Information
{
    var account:String?
    var date:String?
    var name:String?
    var sex:String?
    var born:String?
    var phoneNumber:String?
    var email:String?

    typealias DownlaodComplete = () -> ()

    init(account:String,date:String,name:String,sex:String,born:String,phoneNumber:String,email:String) {
        self.account = account
        self.date = date
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex
        self.born = born
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.email = email
    }


    func downlaodInformation(completion:@escaping DownlaodComplete) {
        Alamofire.request("http://163.18.22.78:81/api/Information/A1001a").responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            completion()
            if let json = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any>
            {
                print("Dictionary done")

                guard
                    let account = json["Account"] as? String,
                    let date = json["Date"] as? String ,
                    let name = json["Name"] as? String else
                {
                    print("Parse error!")
                    return
                }

                self.account = account
                self.date = date
                self.name = name
                /*self.sex = sex
                self.born = born
                self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
                self.email = email*/

                completion()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Tested, and got the following response:

> SUCCESS: {
>       Account = A1001a;
>       Born = 841031;
>       CarParking = "";
>       Date = "0001/1/1 \U4e0a\U5348 12:00:00";
>       Email = "zxc@gmail.com";
>       Name = Ray;
>       Phone = 09361811111;
>       Sex = "\U7537"; } called Dictionary done called